# Converting audio to text and text to audio in ASP.Net Core MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I am implementing an web application that convert speech audio to text and also it should play the displayed text in audio format.I am implementing my application in ASP.NET Core MVC 5.

So can anybody tell me if this can be done it using ASP.NET Core MVC 5 or is there any other way of implementing this idea.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC 5 or ASP.NET Core? Choose one, the combination does not exist.

Comment: I'm using asp.net-core 2.0 mvc 5

Comment: So what have you tried, and where exactly are you stuck? Have you done some basic reasearch, and what have been the results of that research? (i.e. which library are you going to use for Text-to-Speech? What library are you going to use for the speech-to-text? Do you already have any code you can show?)

Comment: No I just researched it, but i'm unable to find the solution and i had no idea too. so refer me for some thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.Net Core` currently is not supporting `Microsoft.Speech` library, so you need to use some API-s to do recognition. For example you can use [Google Speech API](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/)

Comment: Any other API-s other then it.?